# Do raw type declarations take more memory and can lead to memory leak problems?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I want to know, will raw type declarations of generic types will lead to memory leak problem. For example: defining vector as raw in below code

```
Vector shortCutVector = (Vector) request.getAttribute("shortCutVector");
```

Comment: I don't get how it will cause a memory leak problem?

Comment: That's a doubt. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

No, generics doesn't affect memory usage in any way. They're merely a way to provide typing information to the compiler.

In the case of `Vector` (or `ArrayList`, if you don't use ancient classes) the internal storage is still handled by `Object[] arr;`, so it doesn't make any difference what the generic type is.

Even more, the memory usage for an *object reference* is always the same, so `Integer i;` and `String s;` for example would still use the same amount of memory. However when initialized there can of course be a difference in storage, as `Integer i = new Integer(1);` and `String s = "asdasdasd";` clearly require a different amount of space.

Comment: As Java uses type erasure on generics, they even won't be in the code anymore (and be replaced by type casts).

Comment: @René well traces of generic types remain, but they're metadata and don't affect the execution.